# Keep updating if/else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a little issue with my jQuery. I have made a responsive navigation bar and want to add a class called 'mobile' to it when it comes close to the logo.

Here is my code:

```
  function responsiveNav(){
  var navSpace = $(".nav").offset().left;
  if(navSpace < 320){
    $('.nav').addClass('mobile');
    $('.sub-nav').addClass('mobile');
    $('.navbar .container').addClass('container-fluid');
    $('.navbar .container-fluid').removeClass('container');
    $('.navbar-brand > img').css("margin-left", "15px");
    $('.mobile-icon').show();
  } else {
    $('.nav').removeClass('mobile');
    $('.sub-nav').removeClass('mobile');
    $('.navbar .container-fluid').addClass('container');
    $('.navbar .container').removeClass('container-fluid');
    $('.navbar-brand > img').css("margin-left", "0px");
    $('.mobile-icon').hide();
  }
}
$(window).resize(responsiveNav);
$(document).ready(responsiveNav);
```

It does work but when I resize my screen to normal desktop format again my navigation bar still have the 'mobile' class. How can I update my if/else statement so the class will be removed when resizing again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

Could you also post the output of the following line?

```
Menu::showMenu(false, true, 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right');
```

It would be better if you would simply reproduce your problem in a snippet/fiddle.

### Original

I would have added this as a comment, but I do not have enough reputation, so:

I cannot reproduce your problem, but all your code seems ok (see snippet or this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Luc93/kjeu61qu/). Maybe you could give more context?

```js
function responsiveNav(){
  var navSpace = $("#nav").offset().left;
  if(navSpace < 320){
    $('#nav').addClass('mobile');
    $('#nav').removeClass('desktop');
  } else {
    $('#nav').removeClass('mobile');
    $('#nav').addClass('desktop');
  }
}

$(window).resize(responsiveNav);
$(document).ready(responsiveNav);
```

```css
#nav {
  height:100px;
  width:300px;
  float:right;
}

#nav.desktop {
  background:red;
}

#nav.mobile {
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav" class="desktop"></div>
```

Comment: I figured it out, I think I added to much css to the .mobile class. I reduced the amount of style and now it is working. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Wilcovanmeppelen Hmm, that is very weird. Though I doubt that that is the actual problem...

Comment: Yes indeed, it seems very weird for me to. But for now it solved the problem. Maybe I look into it later ;)